# How can I adjust facet width in plotly in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

I'm currently in the process of creating a heatmap with `plotly`. Below is  the sample dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(hrbrthemes)
set.seed(9999)
df <- data.frame(group.int = rep(c(rep("Prevention", 3), "Diagnosis", rep("Intervention", 2)), 6),
                int = rep(c("Prevention 1", "Prevention 2", "Prevention 3", "Diagnosis 1", "Intervention 1", "Intervention 2"), 6),
                group.outcome = c(rep("Efficacy", 12), rep("Safety", 18), rep("Cost-effectiveness", 6)),
                outcome = c(rep("Efficacy 1", 6), rep("Efficacy 2", 6), rep("Safety 1", 6), rep("Safety 2", 6), rep("Safety 3", 6), rep("Cost-effectiveness 1", 6)),
                n = sample(50:250, 36, rep = TRUE)
            )
df$group.int <- factor(df$group.int, levels = c("Prevention", "Diagnosis", "Intervention"))
df$group.outcome <- factor(df$group.outcome, levels = c("Efficacy", "Safety", "Cost-effectiveness"))
```

I want to make a heatmap based on the variable `outcome` against `int`, with `n` as the fill of each heatmap cell. Here is the desired plot:

[image]

I tried using `ggplotly` from the created ggplot:

```
plotly.df <- ggplot(df, 
                aes(x = int, y = outcome, fill= n)) + 
                geom_tile() +
                scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="darkred") +
                scale_y_discrete(position = "right") +
                facet_grid(group.outcome ~ group.int,
                    scales = "free", space = "free", switch = "x") +
                theme_bw() +
                theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                    legend.position = "left",
                    strip.placement = "outside", 
                    strip.background = element_blank())
ggplotly(plotly.df)
```

However, `ggplotly` seems to ignore `space = "free"` in `facet_grid`, so the size of the cells are not proportional:

[image]

Is there a way to adjust facet widths with `ggplotly`?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to reinvent the wheel. Go back to the first `ggplotly` object. Domain is what plotly uses to govern the spaces each facet (or as it is in plotly-subplot). You can retrieve this information by assigning the ggplotly graph to an object and calling `plotly_json`.

However, I've worked around layout shortcuts before. You can retrieve and modify the domains like this:

```
p = ggplotly(plotly.df)

p$x$layout$xaxis$domain <- c(0, 1/2) # 6 blocks, 3 in this group 1/6 * 3
p$x$layout$xaxis2$domain <- c(1/2, 2/3) # start at previous position, 1 in this group
p$x$layout$xaxis3$domain <- c(2/3, 1) # remaining space

p$x$layout$yaxis3$domain <- c(0, 1/6) # 1 block in bottom chunks
p$x$layout$yaxis2$domain <- c(1/6, 2/3) # 3 in mid group
p$x$layout$yaxis$domain <- c(2/3, 1) # remaining space
p
```

That got me this far:

[image]

Your bottom labels are still aligned, but the top is not. Additionally, the left bottom label is cut off.

To fix the top labels I used `plotly_json` to figure out where they were at then used the guess-and-check method. To adjust for labels, I modified the margin.

```
# prevention
p$x$layout$annotations[[3]]$x <- 1/4

# diagnosis
p$x$layout$annotations[[4]]$x <- 7/12

p %>% layout(margin = list(t = 40, r = 50, b = 80, l = 130))
```

[image]

---

---

#### Update based on comments

Consider the following as a replacement for everything that follows `p = ggplotly(plotly.df)` (So you won't use anything about this, but you'll see that the code above is still here.)

The facets

```
#------------- position and spacing facets -------------
p$x$layout$xaxis$domain <- c(0, 1/2)    # 6 blocks, 3 in this group 1/6 * 3
p$x$layout$xaxis2$domain <- c(1/2, 2/3) # 1 in this group
p$x$layout$xaxis3$domain <- c(2/3, 1)   # remaining space

p$x$layout$yaxis3$domain <- c(0, 1/6)   # 1 block in bottom chunks
p$x$layout$yaxis2$domain <- c(1/6, 2/3) # 3 in mid group
p$x$layout$yaxis$domain <- c(2/3, 1)    # remaining space
```

The labels

```
#------------- position and spacing labels -------------
# prevention
p$x$layout$annotations[[3]]$x <- 1/4

# diagnosis
p$x$layout$annotations[[4]]$x <- 7/12

# bottom group labels: prevention, diagnosis, intervention/ adjust down
lapply(3:5, function(i){
  p$x$layout$annotations[[i]]$y <<- -0.1575
})

# efficacy, safety and cost effectiveness/ shift right
lapply(6:8, function(i){
  p$x$layout$annotations[[i]]$x <<- 1.25
  p$x$layout$annotations[[i]]$yanchor <<- "top"
})

# int
p$x$layout$annotations[[1]]$y <- -0.07

# outcome
p$x$layout$annotations[[2]]$x <- 1.475
p$x$layout$annotations[[2]]$textangle <- 90 # 180 degree flip
```

The legend

```
#------------- position and spacing legend -------------
# capture the font sizes of the other annotations
tf <- p$x$layout$xaxis$tickfont

# change the font of the group labels
lapply(3:8, function(i){
  p$x$layout$annotations[[i]]$font <<- tf
})

# update the ticks to represent the values of n, not the scale 
getCol <- data.frame(p$x$data[[10]]$marker$colorscale) # capture the scale
getCol$n <- seq(from = 50, to = 208, along.with = 1:300) %>% round(digits = 0)
summary(getCol)
(getVals <- filter(getCol, n %in% seq(50, 200, by = 50)))
#          X1      X2   n
# 1 0.0000000 #FFFFFF  50
# 2 0.3143813 #E5B4A8 100
# 3 0.3177258 #E5B3A7 100
# 4 0.6321070 #C16B57 150
# 5 0.6354515 #C06A56 150
# 6 0.9464883 #941B0E 200
# 7 0.9498328 #931A0E 200 

# the legend
p$x$data[[10]]$marker$colorbar <- list(x = -.2, tickfont = tf,
                                       tickmode = "array",
                                       ticktext = seq(50, 200, by = 50),
                                   # from getVals output
                                       tickvals = c(0, .318, .636, .95),
                                       outlinewidth = 0,
                                       thickness = 20)
```

and finally...

```
# legend and yaxis labels; the final plot
p %>% layout(margin = list(t = 10, r = 170, b = 120, l = 10),
             yaxis = list(side = "right", anchor = "free", position = 1),
             yaxis2 = list(side = "right", anchor = "free", position = 1),
             yaxis3 = list(side = "right", anchor = "free", position = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Not a pretty workaround but this does the trick. Thanks! Btw, do you know how to customize the legend (colorbar) and the position of the x and y labels as well? (I want to position the y-axis labels on the right side of the plot). I couldn't find the right variable in plotly_json for this. I've marked your answer as the solution. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! You're the best!